# PowerShell [System.IO.StreamWriter] to write to console (Write-Host)?

Tags: ios, powershell

I know that I write into a file by using:

```
      $stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "file.txt"
```

As I need to use a stream I really would know if I can replace "file.txt" by something so that what ever is written to the stream is printed to the console (write-host) or to  write-progress?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to do this with just a stream but you could create a function that writes the output to the console and to a stream.

Comment: hmm - I think so too, now after I tried several versions. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at writing a function that will perform both of those operations. This is pretty generic but would take the input that you want from the pipeline and then write to the stream as well as writing the output to the console.

```
# Generic function name modeled after Tee-Object, which outputs to console and file
Function Tee-Object1 {
    Param (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        $InputObject
    )    
    Process {
        # Write to stream
        [void]$Script:Stream.Write($_)
        # Write to console
        $_
    }
}

$Script:stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "file.txt"
# Whatever your data is will be piped into the function
$data | Tee-Object1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Console]::Out now to get a reference to the current stdout stream

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.out?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_Out